# Apply function to tf.keras.Model output to every sample in the batch

Tags: tf.keras, tensorflow1.15

The problem which I am facing is that I am trying to apply a function to every sample in the model output of a keras model while not knowing what the batch size is.

To elaborate this further, I am creating a model on which I am going to use predict_on_batch for. Say the model looks like model = tf.keras.Model(x,y). The shape of y = (batch_size, output_shape), I am trying to apply a function to the output for every sample in the batch_size and return that as the model output